# Access control on web app

Tags: linux, security, jsf

I am making a web app that has a login page (Using Facelets with JSF 2.0) which checks credentials before redirecting to a isLoggedIn or error page. I have access to the server
that the app is deployed on and Tomcat is used as container. I would like to log ip addresses that clearly tries to perform brute force attacks. My idea for now is the following, but I am not sure how to get hold of the offending IP and even if I could it looks a bit clumsy, so what is a standard/good way of doing this? I would prefer not having to use
any other implementation of JSF.

- During login write log messages (from Beans) using a logging framework to an app-specific
  logfile in Tomcat's log folder where failed logins are saved with offending ip and time.
- Create script that reads the log and checks if any ips have a high rate of failed 
  attempts. Add these ips to `hosts.deny`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using realm authentication check [Tomcat's LockOutRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#LockOutRealm). It does not write the `host.deny` file but it also could prevent brute-force attacks.

Comment: I am doing the authentication "bare" hands.